# Можно ли listView передать как параметр в метод?

Tags: c#, listview, словари

Есть несколько listView, в которые передаются разные Dictionary. Пришлось сделать для каждого listView свой метод (как код ниже). Возможно ли listView передать как параметр в метод? Или как решить эту проблему - чтобы остался только один метод.

```
private void AddDictionaryToListView1(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
{

// тут какой-то код

    this.listView1.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.listView1.Items.AddRange(lvItems); }));
}


private void AddDictionaryToListView2(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
{

// тут какой-то код

    this.listView2.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.listView2.Items.AddRange(lvItems); }));
}
```

Comment: Можно, конечно. Вы бы попробовали сначала.

Comment: да пробовал уже.

Comment: Тогда код в студию. В том, который в вопросе, я не вижу следов попыток передать list view.

Comment: это и есть код. ничего другого нет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Если честно, не понял в чем суть вопроса :)

```
private void AddDictionaryToListView(ListView listview, Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
{
    // тут какой-то код
    listView.Invoke(new Action(() => { listView.Items.AddRange(lvItems); }));
}
```

Comment: нет. при вызове метода
AddDictionaryToListView7(listview1, dictionary);

сообщает "имя listview1 отсутствует в текущем контексте".

Comment: @pontekorvo обновите вопрос и покажите ваш полный код.

Comment: Да, этот код как будто лучше. но при вызове

AddDictionaryToListView(listview1, dictionary);

при компиляции сообщает: "имя listview1 отсутствует в текущем контексте",

а если добавить строку 

ListView listview1 = new ListView();
AddDictionaryToListView(listview1, dictionary);

компилируется, но при  исполнении сообщает, что невозможно вызвать Invoke до завершения создания дескриптора окна. 

В общем, ясности пока не стало больше.

Comment: А в чём суть действия "добавить строку ListView listview1 = new ListView()"? Заткнуть компилятор, чтобы не ругался? Вам ведь нужно передать не _какой-то_ экземпляр `ListView`, а вполне конкретный. Откуда вы вызываете ваш код?

Comment: Да, Ваш код работает на 5. 
Не там искал ошибку: в какой-то момент указал в вызове метода listview1 (и т.д.), а у меня listView1 (и т.д.). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно передавать объекты параметром в методы в виде :

```
public void example(Object o)
```

Таким образом, чтобы передать ListView:

```
public void example(ListView listV){
// code here
}
```

Перед тем,как вызвать метод :

```
ListView listV = this;
```

Final:

```
ListView listV = this;
AddDictionaryToListView2(listV);
private void AddDictionaryToListView2(Dictionary<string, ListView listV){

this.listView2.Invoke(new Action(() => { listV.listView2.Items.AddRange(lvItems); }));
```

Comment: Если вы внимательно посмотрите на теги, там речь идёт о C#. Впрочем, это не должно повлиять на суть ответа.

Comment: ListView listV = this;
эта строка даже не компилируется.

Comment: Вы давно программируете? Покажите код. В каких условиях вы вызываете метод?

Comment: Программирую не давно :-))) Решение найдено.

Answer (score 0):

Работает такой код:

`DictionaryToListView(listView1, dictionary);`

```
private void DictionaryToListView(ListView listview, Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
        {
// тут какой-то код

            listview.Invoke(new Action(() => { listview.Items.AddRange(lvItems); }));
        }
```